# Count of $3 \times 3$ matrices with sum $> 21$

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

What is the number of $3 \times 3$ matrices that can be formed using first $9$ natural numbers at most once such that sum of elements in at least one row or column is greater than $21$?

---

What I've tried to do so far:

The combinations of $3$ digits that add up to $21$ are $(5,8,9), (6,7,9), (6,8,9), (7,8,9): 4$ ways.

These 4 can either be one of the 3 rows or columns so that is $(_1^6)\times 4\times3!$
Then for the last 6 digits, they can be arranged in $6!$ ways. So I think the answer should be $6\times4\times3!\times6!$ However, the answer given is $119\times(3!)^2\times4!$.

I need help identifying the errors in my solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: What if a row is $(5,8,9)$ and a column is $(6,7,9)$?

Comment: The answer, as verified by @138 Aspen, is $101952$, which is not $119\times 3!^2\times 4!$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you overcounted the cases where the row containing $9$ and the column containing $9$ both sum to a number larger than $21$.

Let's say you first choose $(9,5,8)$ as the first row.
Then you choose
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 1 & 2 \\
7 & 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as the remaining $6$ entries.
The final matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
9 & 5 & 8 \\
6 & 1 & 2 \\
7 & 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now, if you first choose $(9,6,7)$ as the first column,
and choose
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 8 \\
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as the remaining $6$ entries,
then you also get the same final matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
9 & 5 & 8 \\
6 & 1 & 2 \\
7 & 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
However, since we have made different choices to generate the final matrix,
your method regards these two cases as different cases
and thus overcounts.

---

As you noted, only the following combinations sum to a number larger than $21$:
$$
(5,8,9),\ (6,7,9),\ (6,8,9),\ (7,8,9)
$$
They all contain the number $9$,
so we can first choose the position of $9$.
Obviously, there are $3^2$ positions we can place the number $9$.
Then the matrix can be partitioned as follows:

1. The entry that contains $9$
2. The other $2$ entries that are in the row $R$ containing $9$
3. The other $2$ entries that are in the column $C$ containing $9$
4. The remaining $2\times 2$ submatrix

Observe that there are the following symmetries:

1. Swapping the two non-$9$ entries in $R$
2. Swapping the two non-$9$ entries in $C$
3. Swapping $R$ and $C$
4. Permuting the $4$ entries in the $2\times 2$ submatrix above

This gives the factor $2^3\cdot 4!$.
Finally, we have to choose the numbers that appear in $R$ and $C$ (and the remaining entries in the $2\times 2$ submatrix are automatically chosen).
Note that the only case where $R$ and $C$ both sum to a number larger than $21$ is when $R=\{5,8,9\}$ and $C=\{6,7,9\}$ (up to swapping $R$ and $C$, which has been accounted),
so the number of ways to choose numbers in $R$ and $C$ is:
$$
\underbrace{{6\choose 2}}_{R=\{7,8,9\}}+
\underbrace{{6\choose 2}}_{R=\{6,8,9\}}+
\underbrace{{6\choose 2}-1}_{R=\{6,7,9\},C\ne\{5,8,9\}}+
\underbrace{{6\choose 2}-1}_{R=\{5,8,9\},C\ne\{6,7,9\}}+
\underbrace{1}_{R=\{5,8,9\},C=\{6,7,9\}}=
59
$$
In summary, the answer is
$$
3^2\cdot 2^3\cdot 4!\cdot 59=101952.
$$
As said in my comment, the given answer is incorrect.

Comment: Ask, if the steps are not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's clear to me now.

Comment: @HappyGnocchi Actually, the only overcounted cases with your method is the one mentioned in my answer, so you can exclude those $3^2\cdot 2^3\cdot 4!=1728$ cases. Then $6\cdot 4\cdot 3!\cdot 6!-1728=101952$, which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
(*Mathematica*)
checkMatrix@m_ := 
  Max[Total /@ m] > 21 || Max[Total /@ Transpose[m]] > 21;
Permutations[Range[1, 9, 1]] // Map[Partition[#, 3] &, #] & // 
  Select[#, checkMatrix] & // Length
```

$$
101952
$$